# I am getting LocalUnboundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

This is my views.py file:

```
url = "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics"
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "c5e4f10fa8msh519e24367741e55p1dcabajsn27df4eda14e0",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
def home(request):
    noofresults = int(response['results'])
    mylist = []
    for x in range(0,noofresults):
        mylist.append(response['response'][x]['country'])    
    if request.method=='POST':
        selectedcountry= request.POST['selectedcountry']
        # noofresults = int(response['results'])
        for x in range(0,noofresults):
            if selectedcountry==response['response'][x]['country']:
                new = response['response'][x]['cases']['new']
                active = response['response'][x]['cases']['active']
                critical = response['response'][x]['cases']['critical']
                recoverd = response['response'][x]['cases']['recovered']
                total = response['response'][x]['cases']['total']
                deaths = int(total)-int(active) - int(recoverd)    
        context = {'selectedcountry':selectedcountry,'mylist':mylist, 'new':new, 'active':active, 'critical':critical, 'recoverd':recoverd, 'total':total, 'deaths':deaths}
        return render(request,'home.html',context)                
    context = {'mylist': mylist}
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

The error i am getting after selecting a country is:

> UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'new' referenced before assignment

Comment: Initialize `new, active, critical, recoverd, total, deaths` before for loop

Answer (score -1):

I'm not much into Python, but here to help.

You're using the `new` variable at the time of declaration, I believe, which causes the error "UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'new' referenced before assignment."

`new = response['response'][x]['cases']['new']`

Comment: That's not quite it. The issue is that if the `if selectedcountry ...` statement doesn't get executed, there will be no `new` value.